# "is" operator result: What is happening?

Tags: python

I was quite surprised when

```
[] is not []
```

evaluated to `True`.

What is happening in this code? What really `not` and `is` statements are doing?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`a is not b` is a special operator which is equivalent to `not a is b`.

The operator `a is b` returns True if a and b are bound to the same object, otherwise False. When you create two empty lists you get two different objects, so `is` returns False (and therefore `is not` returns True).

Comment: *if a and b are the same object* - I would like *are bound to the same object* even better.

Answer (score 36):

`is` is the identity comparison.

`==` is the equality comparison.

Your statement is making two different lists and checking if they are the same instance, which they are not. If you use `==` it will return true and because they are both empty lists.

Answer (score 25):

The best way to describe WHY that happens is this:

Here is your example

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = []
>>> print(x is y)
... False
```

`x` and `y` are actually two different lists, so if you add something to `x`, it does not appear in `y`

```
>>> x.append(1)
>>> print(x)
... [1]
>>> print(y)
... []
```

So how do we make (`x is y`) evaluate true?

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = x
>>> print(x is y)
... True

>>> x.append(10)

>>> print(x)
... [10]
>>> print(y)
... [10]

>>> print(x is y)
... True
```

if you want to see if two lists have the same contents...

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = []
>>> print(x == y)
... True

>>> x.append(21)

>>> print(x)
... [21]
>>> print(y)
... []

>>> print(x == y)
... False

>>> y = [21]
>>> print(x == y)
... True
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but, after reading [this](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/reference/expressions.html#id26) in Python reference, I get confused:


_Due to automatic garbage-collection, free lists, and the dynamic nature of descriptors, **you may notice seemingly unusual behaviour in certain uses of the is operator**, like those involving comparisons between instance methods, or constants._

Comment: "..so if you add something to x, it does not appear in y" - that seems wrong to me. Try `a="test";b="test";a is b`. It will give you `True` even though changing one will not change the other.

Comment: @Pithikos that is the because of an optimization in the particular version of python you are using, it is not a guarantee. Also, strings are immutable so you cannot change one of those values. you can only assign a new string to the same variable.

Answer (score 8):

`is` means *is same instance*. It evaluates to true if the variables on either side of the operator point to the same object and false otherwise.

[Reference](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/comparisons.html), near the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

is checks for identity. `[]` and `[]` are two different (but equivalent) lists. If you want to check if both the lists are empty you can use their truth value (false for empty strings, collections, and zeros).

```
if not ([] and []):
   print 'Spanish Inquisition'
```

the only time that `is` is guaranteed to return True is for singletons such as None. Like the Highlander, there can be only one instance of None in your program - every time you return None it's the very same "thing" as the none referred to if you type `print None`.

[], OTOH, is not guaranteed to be anything except an empty list and evaluate to False in a boolean context.

Comment: `a = b`.  I believe that we are now guaranteed that `a is b`.

Comment: @recursive, do you know if that's the case for strings/numbers?

Comment: As far as I know, it's true for everything.  When you assign `b` to `a` in python, you are assigning `a` to be a reference to the object currently referenced by `b`.  So their identity will be identical.  It's python, so it may be possible to do some weird thing like overriding assignment to break this, but in general, I'd say yes.

Comment: I guess that makes sense - and is different from `a = "hi"; b = "hi"` which `is` behavior is *not* guaranteed aside from returning True or False.

Comment: When I execute this `[] and []` evaluates to `[]`...what does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am posting to a pretty old post. however, this might help someone stumble upon this like me.

"is" checks, whether a memory address is same or not, while "==" check if the value is same or not.  Would be much clear from the following example

let's first talk about immutable objects, as it's easy to understand

```
# could be any immutable object
immutable_a = 10
immutable_b = 10

# prints address of a and b variable
print "address of a is %s" % id(immutable_a)
print "address of a is %s" % id(immutable_b)

# as both addresses is same, following shall be true
print immutable_a is immutable_b

# as the values are also same, following shall be true as well
print immutable_a == immutable_b
```

now let's talk about mutable objects

```
# could be any mutable object
mutable_a = [10]
mutable_b = [10]

# prints address of a and b variable
print "address of mutable_a is %s" % id(mutable_a)
print "address of mutable_b is %s" % id(mutable_b)

# as addresses are not same, following shall be false
print mutable_a is mutable_b

# as the values are same, following shall be true
print mutable_a == mutable_b
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jiaaro is right. Using `is` with immutable data types is dangerous because it is not predictable because of Pythons interpreter optimization.

See this example:

```
10 * "a" is 10 * "a"    # True
100 * "a" is 100 * "a"  # False
```

In the second line it is faster to create a new object with a new id for the interpreter. So use the `is` operator only with mutable types.