# python checking for value doesnt work

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am looking for a value "Not found" but my code is not finding it. Instead if the value is Not Found it just crashes

here is the code

```
for key, value in productLinks.iteritems():
        if value is "Not Found":
                 print value
        else:
                 print value
                 html = urllib2.urlopen(value)
                 soup = BS(html)
                 foundPrice = soup.find('s')
                 if found is not None:
                        print "found a price"
                 else:
                        print" No Lunk"
```

here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asimsScrapper.py", line 28, in <module>
    html = urllib2.urlopen(value)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 386, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 248, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: Not found
```

Comment: "Not Found" is different from "Not found", right?

Comment: So smart, Alexis. So smart.

Answer (score 4):

`is` keyword is used for identity comparison, type checking.

You probably wanted to use `==`:

```
if value == "Not Found"
```

Also, instead of checking for a `Not Found` (or `Not found`) string, you can validate the url, like this:

```
for key, value in productLinks.iteritems():
    if value.startswith('http'):
         print value
         html = urllib2.urlopen(value)
         ...
```

Or, even better use [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to validate the url.

See also:

- [Python "is" statement: what is happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718513/python-is-statement-what-is-happening)
- [How is the 'is' keyword implemented in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987958/how-is-the-is-keyword-implemented-in-python)

Comment: Okay, `is` is not used for type checking in python, it (essentially) checks memory address. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers or one of the other thousands of references on this material.

Comment: @ap ok, thank you, what is important is that the OP shouldn't use it here.

Comment: It also is immaterial to the actual issue at hand, apparently. He seems to be trying to use the string "Not found" as a url and pass that back up through libraries to his glue code. Python doesn't have a built in "not found" monad, so that's not going to work...

Comment: Jesus everyone is upvoting this because it addresses what appears to be an obvious problem -- READ the question before responding. His trace should give some evidence that this is not the problem at hand. Open ipy and type `__import__('urllib2').urlopen('not found')` and I promise you'll get the same error. Figure it out SOirclejerkers.

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(value),
unknown url type: Not found
```

You are trying to open a `url = "Not found"`

the root cause is: `value is "Not found"`, please use: `value == "Not found"`.

Answer (score 0):

alecxe is right in that you should use `==` to check value equivalence, but his reasons are wrong. When in doubt, always test equivalence with `==` -- `is` simply tests for *identity*, which is different from equivalence. Identity has more to do with where something is stored in memory than what that value in memory is. There are a number of places to read about this on SO and elsewhere, but the takeaway is that `is` is not `==`.

Your error seems to be unrelated to this. If you try to `urllib2.urlopen("not found")` it's definitely going to give you exactly this error. You want to try to catch it before passing it to `urllib2`.