# "A is not B" vs "A is (not B)"

Tags: python

I'm a little bit scared about the "is not" operator and the possibility that "is not X" is interpreted when "is (not X)" was intended. Do exist some expressions A and B such that:

```
A is not B
```

is different from

```
A is (not B)
```

?

**addendum**.
Is it considered good practice to use this operator? Should't `not (A is B)` be preferred?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python "is" statement: what is happening?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718513/python-is-statement-what-is-happening)

Comment: In some cases, `not B` will be an error, if `B` can't be used as an implicit Boolean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

```
A = 0
B = 1
```

Try it and you'll be really scared:

```
>>> A = 0
>>> B = 1
>>> A is not B
True
>>> A is (not B)
False
```

Answer (score 10):

They're definitely different.  The latter case evaluates `not X` in a boolean context first and then checks to see if the two objects *are the same object* (either `True` or `False`).

Consider:

```
False is not []
```

This expression is trivially `True` since `False` and `[]` are quite clearly different objects. <sup>1</sup>

vs.

```
False is (not [])
```

This expression is `False` since `not []` evalutes to `True` and `False` and `True` are different objects.

Of course, this is just one example.  It gets even easier to find examples if you don't use `False` and `True` explicitly as the second expression will *always* be `False` and the first expression will (almost) always be `True`...

```
3 is not 0   # True
3 is (not 0)   # False
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that [`is not`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.is_not) is a **single operator** in the same vein as `not in`.</sup>

Comment: Same result for me in Python 2.7 and Python 3.3. Use `False is not []` to see a difference.

Comment: @Matthias -- Thanks.  Early morning brain fog I guess.  I'm always surprised by the number of upvotes you can pull in even with a wrong answer :-)