# Comparing of two big int must not same but it is diffrent python3

Tags: python, oop, int

```
>>>s1 = 100
>>>s2 = 100
>>>s1 is s2
True
>>>b1 = 257
>>>b2 = 257
>>>
>>>b11 = b12 = 257
>>>b1 is b2
False
>>>
>>>b11 is b12
True
>>>
```

b1 and b2 is `False` because of `PyLongtObject` what happen on b11 and b12? 
any idea please help me.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718513/python-is-statement-what-is-happening

Comment: Or duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Comment: sory I just made a small mistake.

Comment: see this better understanding click [here](https://jawahar273.gitbooks.io/into-python-for-students/content/know-this/question-7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a (convoluted) duplicate of [About the changing id of a Python immutable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245324/about-the-changing-id-of-a-python-immutable-string).

During evaluation phase in REPL loop only one constant with value 257 is created in memory.

```
compile("a = b = 257", '<stdin>', 'single').co_consts  # (257, None)
```

When executing, same object (with same address in memory) is assigned to both names.

```
>>> dis.dis(compile("a = b = 257", '<stdin>', 'single'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (257)
              3 DUP_TOP             
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              7 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Since both names point to same object, it's expected that `id` on those objects returns same number, therefore `is` returns `True`.

Comment: Ehm, what? It's just an explanation of a behavior that's implementation detail and is not guaranteed by language specification. Always compare integers by equality, never by identity and you're good to go.

Comment: thanq for the comment