# Why does "[] is [ ]" evaluate to False in python

Tags: python, list

Try this in an interactive python shell.

```
[] is [ ]
```

The above returns False, why?

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think it should be true?

Comment: `[] is []` will also fail: the two are **different objects**. `is` does a **reference equality check**.

Comment: Why should this be true? You created two empty mutable objects, you wouldn't *want* them to be the same object.

Comment: Why the minus votes? It is a legitimate question. The OP didn't know that is checks reference equality.

Comment: @Giacomod'Antonio: that's easy to research however. The OP didn't share any of their research, nor did they explain why they expected this expression to be true. You are assuming that they confused `is` with `==` (the value equality operator), but perhaps they thought it would be efficient instead? For example, for two empty tuple expressions this would be true: `() is ()`, as is `1 is 1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then why did you answer?

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: badly researched != off-topic. And I'm assuming there was no research only because nothing in the question shows otherwise.

Comment: fair enough, thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718513/python-is-statement-what-is-happening

Comment: @Jonathan read up on the difference between `is` and `==` and it should answer your question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You created two *mutable objects*, then used `is` to see if those are the *same object*. That should definitely return `False`, or something would be broken.

You wouldn't ever want `is` to return true here. Imagine if you did this:

```
foo = []
bar = []
foo.append(42)
```

then you'd be very surprised if `bar` now contains `42`. If `is` returned true, meaning that both `[]` invocations returned the exact same object, then appending to `foo` would be visible in the reference to `bar`.

For *immutable* objects, it makes sense to cache objects, at which point `is` **may** return true, like with empty tuples:

```
>>> () is ()  # are these two things the same object?
True
```

The CPython implementation has optimised empty tuple creation; you'll always get the exact same object, because that saves memory and makes certain operations faster. Because tuples are immutable, this is entirely safe.

If you expected to test for *value equality* instead, then you got the wrong operator. Use the `==` operator instead:

```
>>> [] == []  # do these two objects have the same value?
True
```

Answer (score 1):

In python `is` does a `reference equality check` like [] and [] they are different objects you can check that by

```
print id([]),id([])
```

or

```
 In [1]: id([])
Out[1]: 140464629086976

In [2]: id([])
Out[2]: 140464628521656
```

**both will return different address and both are different object so is will always give false**

```
[] is []
```

**output**

```
false
```

Comment: Those `id` tests aren't doing what you think they are. It's quite common for the `print` to print the same number twice, because the lists don't have overlapping lifetimes. Similarly, this is why your `==` test with `id` values gave True instead of False.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is like `list()`, if you do this:

```
a = list()
b = list()
```

clearly `a` and `b` are two completly different objects, hence:

```
a is b # False
```

like

```
list() is list() # False
```

like

```
[] is [] # False
```

Comment: Why does it matter what way the empty list objects were created?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it does not matter, maybe i did not explained well, or you did not understand what i would like to explain?

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't matter if you use `[] is []` or `list() is list()`; both expressions create empty list objects. To say that *`[]` is like `list()`* you are not explaining anything about why the `is` test returns `False`, because the difference between `[]` and `list()` doesn't matter here. Also, your `== False` tests are incorrect; you are testing if `(a is b) and (b == False)`, because Python comparison operators are *chained*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ok so i explained badly, i was just poiting that `[]` and `list()` both build objects, and in each call both build diferent objects, so it was obvious that `[] is []` would be evaluated to false. About the operators, it was just me relaxing and writting python sintax for making the point, not written reliable python code, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. Whereas `is` operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not.

```
id('') : 139634828889200
id('') : 139634828889200
id('') : 139634828889200

id([]) : 139634689473416
id([]) : 139634689054536
id([]) : 139634742570824
```