# Why [] is [] gives False in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm bit confused with this logic. When the following gives True in python

```
print('' is '')  #True
print('' == '')  #True
print([] ==  []) #True
print({} ==  {}) #True
```

But why these statement gives False?

```
print([] is  []) #False
print({} is  {}) #False
```

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553259/why-does-is-evaluate-to-false-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The == operator compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. Whereas is operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-operator-python/

Comment: Then why `'' is ''` gives `True` if it comparing the objects?

Comment: @Vanjith: Because both `''` expressions happened to evaluate to the same object. This is permitted but not required for immutable objects.