# Difference in handling of tuples in python shell vs IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, tuples

I was learning about python tuples when I encountered a weird inconsistency. This code:

```
x = (1,2)
y = (1,2)
print(x is y)
```

This gives False in shell but True in IDLE. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Are they both using the same version of Python?

Comment: Good catch Fitz.  I can confirm I see the same difference.  Python 3.8.  Strange

Comment: Python makes **no promises** about whether two equal (deeply) immutable values will be represented by the same object. Some cases get optimized. Some don't. Such optimizations are not part of the language definition and should not be relied upon.

Comment: Try ==. Does it still happen?

Comment: @Kral.  That fixes it, at least for me

Comment: `is` is used if both have same `id` i.e. referring to same object then true, use `==`

Comment: I saw this recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718513/python-is-statement-what-is-happening

Comment: a = 1, b=2-1, `a is b` `True`, I think it is upto interpreter logic to create new object or not

Comment: @Epsi95 that is a particular CPython optimization that caches small `int` objects

Answer (score -3):

Actually Python IDLE and shell uses different storage system for data types  like tuple-()
All other data types like :

- list
- set
- dict

are goning to show the same.

Comment: @Kral `is` and `==` are different.

Comment: "Actually Python IDLE and shell uses different storage system for data types like tuple" no, that is absolutely not true.

Comment: Ok then why please tell

Comment: There are many possible reasons, idle may be executing the whole block, where the peep-hole optimizer has optimized an immutable literal into being the same object, whereas in the shell, the blocks are separated, so the optimization doesn't happen. There are no "different storage systems" for specific data types in Python IDLE, that doesn't make any sense, IDLE is just an IDE, it isn't a separate runtime.